# Creating a C# dll for Easylanguage

Tags: c#

I am an experience Easylanguage coder. Easylanguage is a high level language used by Tradestation (trading platform). Easylanguage can utilize dlls as in this example:

```
DefineDLLFunc:  "Calculator.dll", float, "Subtract", float, float;
```

I have created the Calculator.dll using Visual Studio 2019.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    Public class Functions
    {
            public float Subtract(float a, float b)
            {
                return a - b;
            }

            public float Multiply(float a, float b)
            {
                return a * b;
            }

            public float Divide(float a, float b)
            {
                return a / b;
            }

            public float Power(float a)
            {
                return a * a;
            }
    }
}
```

I did the build step and it created the dll file, but this is lacking something because when I try to access the dll from Easylanguage, it cannot find any of the functions. I'm missing a step or two on production of the dll. What is it?

Comment: When you say "Easylanguage can utilize dlls" - Windows native DLLs, or .NET DLLs? If Easylanguage doesn't support .NET, you'd need to initialize a host yourself (which will be tricky).

Comment: Yes, it supports .NET.

Comment: In that case I suspect you'll need to refer us to some documentation... otherwise you're only going to get help from others who know Easylanguage, and I suspect there aren't many of those on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [link]https://community.tradestation.com/Discussions/Topic.aspx?Topic_ID=140070

Comment: @Atom you need to write COM classes per that link. It's not quite the same as "normal" .NET

Comment: Right, so it sounds like Easylanguage *doesn't* naturally support .NET - it supports COM, and you can expose .NET classes via COM... that's not really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use DefineDLLFunc to call .NET assemblies. This method only seems to work for native DLLs and not managed (.NET) DLLs. For .NET DLLs you may have to use COM. This is just a guess, because I'm not familiar with EasyLanguage. But you may check this website for interop with EasyLanguage: https://www.tradestationchina.com.cn/knowledge-base-/understanding-tradestation-compatible-dlls-part-iii/